# Longest words in dictionary that can be constructed from a list of letters

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

The problem is to find the longest words in a dictionary of legal words that can be constructed from a given list of letters.

For example:

> ```
> $ ./scrabble dictionary.txt i g h l p r a
> argil glair grail graph hilar laigh phial pilar ralph
> ```

More details [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/n3arf/python_quiz_of_the_week_1/).

I've already solved this problem in Python (see [this](https://gist.github.com/1441776)).

To brush up my C++ I decided to reproduce the exact same algorithm in C++. I learned C++ as "C with classes" and never learned to use the STL properly, so I usually end up writing more code than necessary to accomplish simple things.

This is what I came up with for this problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool can_make(string word, vector<char> letters);
int get_max_len(vector<string> words);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Grab the dictionary.
    fstream dict_file(argv[1]);
    string in;
    vector<string> dict_words;
    while(getline(dict_file, in)) dict_words.push_back(in);
    dict_file.close();

    // Get the list of input letters.
    vector<char> letters;
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
        letters.push_back(argv[i][0]);

    // Get all words.
    vector<string> all_words;
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = dict_words.begin(); it < dict_words.end(); it++)
        if (can_make(*it, letters))
            all_words.push_back(*it);

    // Get longest words.
    int max_len = get_max_len(all_words);
    vector<string> longest_words;
    for (it = all_words.begin(); it < all_words.end(); it++)
        if ((*it).length() == max_len)
            longest_words.push_back(*it);

    // Print the result.
    for (it = longest_words.begin(); it < longest_words.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}


bool can_make(string word, vector<char> letters)
{
    /*
        Return true if the word <word> can be generated by all letters in <letters>
        and only the letters in <letters>.
    */

    if (word.length() > letters.size()) return false;

    vector<char> l(letters);
    vector<char> word_letters(word.c_str(), word.c_str()+word.length());
    vector<char>::iterator it, loc;

    // Iterate through <word_letters>. If a letter in <word_letters> also
    // appears in <letters>, remove it. Otherwise, return false.
    for (it = word_letters.begin(); it < word_letters.end(); it++) {
        loc = find(letters.begin(), letters.end(), *it);
        if (loc == letters.end()) return false;
        letters.erase(loc);
    }

    return true;
}


int get_max_len(vector<string> words)
{
    /*
        Return the length of the longest word(s) in <words>.
    */

    int max_len = 0;
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = words.begin(); it < words.end(); it++)
        if ((*it).length() > max_len)
            max_len = (*it).length();

    return max_len;
}
```

1. Is this idiomatic C++?
2. How can I make this code more concise?
3. How can I make it more correct?
4. What C++11 features can I use here to make the code even shorter?
5. What features have I used here that I should avoid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post expands on the answers already given. First, some more comments about your code:

### Argument Checking

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fstream dict_file(argv[1]);
    // ...
```

You should check the supplied arguments before using them. Executing your program with no arguments would access an out-of-bound index.

### Vectors everywhere

```
vector<string> dict_words;
while(getline(dict_file, in)) dict_words.push_back(in);
// ...
vector<char> letters;
for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    letters.push_back(argv[i][0]);
// ...
vector<string> all_words;
vector<string>::iterator it;
for (it = dict_words.begin(); it < dict_words.end(); it++)
// ...
int max_len = get_max_len(all_words);
vector<string> longest_words;
// ...
```

That's quite a number of vectors you've made there. I'm not convinced they're all necessary.

```
bool can_make(string word, vector<char> letters);
int get_max_len(vector<string> words);
```

To make this usage even more gratuitous you pass those vectors by value too!

### Accepting entire argument

```
// Get the list of input letters.
vector<char> letters;
for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    letters.push_back(argv[i][0]);
```

Here I think it makes more sense to use the entire argument as letters. If need be you can check its input with something like `isalpha`.

### Performance implications

```
bool can_make(string word, vector<char> letters)
{
    // ...
    vector<char> l(letters);
    // ...
    for (it = word_letters.begin(); it < word_letters.end(); it++) {
        // ...
        letters.erase(loc);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Using `letters.erase(loc);` liberally in a loop like this can result in severe performance problems especially if the vector contains *lots* of letters. This is due to the [linear performance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase) characteristics of `vector::erase` where removed items have to get shifted over. Also note that your `vector<char> l(letters);` is unused here.

### And finally... a practical example

As others have hinted, you can cutdown on syntactic noise and improve readability(greatly) by using algorithms supplied by the standard library. If you're brushing up on C++ this advice might be fuzzy for you. As an example, here's how I'd do it under the true spirit of generic programming:

You'll need the following headers for the example to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;    // for convenience only -- don't do this on real projects
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        // Print some error out
        return -1;
    }

    vector<string> dictionary;
    load_dictionary(argv[1], back_inserter(dictionary));

    string letters = grab_letters(argv + 2, argv + argc);

    deque<string> results;
    for_each(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), try_match(letters, results));

    // No words could be matched
    if(results.empty()) return 0;

    // Remove short words.
    while(results.back().length() > results.front().length())
        results.pop_front();

    copy(results.begin(),
         results.end(),
         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
}
```

Even without comments, the code above is very understandable. The general usage pattern is to perform some *action* on a set of *inputs*. The action is communicated by the algorithm's name (eg. load_dictionary, for_each, copy etc.). The input is specified as a range given by the pair of iterators. Some actions, like copy, take one more iterator to indicate where to copy to.

This is similar to Sjoerd's `grab_dictionary` function but modified to accept other containers besides vectors.

```
template <typename T>
void load_dictionary(const char *filename, T appender)
{
    ifstream infile(filename);
    if(!infile) return;

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(infile),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         appender);
}
```

Notice the usage of iterator adapters like `istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator`. With those constructs it allows algorithms to work with almost any kind of iostream as if it's another container.

```
template <typename T>
string grab_letters(T begin, const T &end)
{
    string letters;
    while(begin != end) letters += *begin++;

    return letters;
}
```

Even `grab_letters` follow this pattern for processing extra arguments passed in. This works because conceptually iterators are pointers. That means you can use `char *argv[]` to indicate where the first argument starts and where it ends.

```
// Get all words.
deque<string> results;
for_each(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), try_match(letters, results));
```

This is where the real processing happens. The `try_match` function creates a *functor* (conveniently named matcher) and passes it to `for_each`. When `for_each` visits each word in turn, it will call the functor via the overloaded `operator ()` with the current word as argument.

```
template <typename T>
class matcher
{
public:
    matcher(const string &letters, T &results);
    void operator ()(const string &word);
};

template <typename T>
matcher<T> try_match(const string &letters, T &results)
{
    return matcher<T>(letters, results);
}
```

And from here you can just write whatever processing needs to happen in the matcher functor class.

Comment: In your example please insert the header needed.

Comment: Note: You do not even need to load the dictionary in memory: for_each(std::istream_iterator<string>(dictFile), std::istream_iterator<string>(), try_match(letters, results));

Comment: @Loki That's a good observation, I haven't thought of that. But then again it is starting to be quite a mouthful. D:

Comment: Wow, your practical example is just the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Ankur you're welcome, glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 8):

### Preface

I am not sure the algorithm you have chosen is the best one. Sorting the letters, or using a frequency table of the letters, are obvious alternatives. However, this is *code review*, and not *algorithm review*.

So here we go:

### Iterators

**Don't use `<` on iterators, use `!=` on iterators**. `<` only works on bidirectional iterators, `!=` works on all iterators. `std::list<>` is an example where `<` won't work.

**Use `++it` instead of `it++`**. Theoretically, the latter has to return a temporary copy of the original, which is additional overhead when the iterator is a class. Practically, it won't make much of a difference (if any) as most compilers will inline and optimize. Still, it's one of the best signals whether someone is a true C++ expert or a converted C-programmer :P .

So

```
for (it = dict_words.begin(); it < dict_words.end(); it++)
```

Will become:

```
for (it = dict_words.begin(); it != dict_words.end(); ++it)
```

### Predefined algorithms

Many of your one-line loops can be replaced with algorithms from `<algorithm>`.

In this small case, I wouldn't bother as it wouldn't help to make your code more clear or shorter.

On the other hand, experimenting with them in this case will make you more comfortable with them. With the introduction of lambdas in C++11, those algorithms will become much more common in new code!

### C++11

Due to the fact that C++11 hasn't been around long yet (and compilers don't fully implement it yet), *idiomatic C++11* will change over the next couple years. So take this section with a grain of salt.

That being said, use `auto` for the type of `it`. That part of C++11 has become idiomatic already.

E.g.:

```
vector<string>::iterator it;
for (it = dict_words.begin(); it != dict_words.end(); ++it)
```

will become:

```
for (auto it = dict_words.begin(); it != dict_words.end(); ++it)
```

EDIT: oops, forgot about the **range-based for in C++11**. See other answers for that. I'm not that well versed in C++11 yet, but I believe it would look like this:

```
for (auto it : dict_words)
```

### More functions

Most of your code is in one long function, called `main`. Try to split it up.

Once you start inserting empty lines and comment headings to clarify what the block does, it's usually a good candidate to turn into a separate function.

E.g. this block of code (limited by empty lines, with a comment):

```
// Grab the dictionary.
fstream dict_file(argv[1]);
string in;
vector<string> dict_words;
while(getline(dict_file, in)) dict_words.push_back(in);
dict_file.close();
```

Can be replaced with this function:

```
void grab_dictionary(const char* filename, vector<string>& dict_words)
{
    fstream dict_file(filename);
    string in;
    while(getline(dict_file, in))
       dict_words.push_back(in);
}
```

Usage from main:

```
vector<string> dict_words;
grab_dictionary(argv[1], dict_words);
```

Additional benefit:

- The comment is no longer needed - usually it has become the name of the function!
- There is no need for `dict_file.close()` as the destructor will close the file at the right time.

Comment: Thanks! I have a few more questions: why should I use ++it instead of it++? Why is it != letters.end() better than it < letters.end()? And since we are on the topic, could you suggest a better algorithm for this task?

Comment: @AnkurSethi Thanks for accepting my answer! However, my answer contains only a few basic rewrites; Other answers all contain valid points as well. IMHO, VictorT's answer comes closest to code a real C++ guru would write.

Comment: yes, VictorT's answer is indeed very good. Great example of generic programming there, just what I was looking for. I think it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You use too much of copying from one vector to another.
Use filtering.

Instead of

```
vector<string>::iterator it;
for (it = words.begin(); it < words.end(); it++)
```

use

```
for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin(), E = words.end(); it != E; ++it)
```

In C++11 you should use `auto` wherever it's possible,
use begin/end functions instead of begin/end methods,
and use range-based `for` loop for iterating over collections.

Your `can_make` is non-optimal and probably is wrong. (Python solution is non-optimal too).

`int get_max_len(vector<string> words)`
 - don't pass `words` by value until ypu really need to copy it.
 - it should return value of `size_t` type, enable warnings in your compiler, and enable "treat warnings as errors" option.

---

**Upd:** @LokiAstari wrote that it's bad practice to write `E = words.end(); it != E`, because "The containers are already optimized to do this efficiently.".
In common case, it's incorrect.
It's true that in some trivial cases, **compiler** can infer that contatiner isn't modified in loop body, and perform such optimization.
But if container is referenced in loop body by non-const reference, compiler can't assume that container isn't modified, so it will get `end()` iterator on every iteration.
It't the same as `; ++i)` vs. `; i++)` - in trivial cases, compiler will optimize `i++` to `++i`, but in non-trivial cases it will not do it.

Comment: Don't do **E = words.end(); it != E**. The containers are already optimized to do this efficiently. So you gain nothing, the cost is that it makes the code brittle to change.

Comment: @LokiAstari, can you prove it? What container and what its implementation has such optimization?

Comment: All of them. This is such a common way of doing things (calling end() after each iteration, that it was one of the first optimizations to the STL) check your copy of the STL. Even if they do not have it your code is brittle to change.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I don't believe you, but I believe my experience, and some coding standards, like this - http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#ll_end .

Comment: Assume I am wrong. It still makes your code more brittle. Thus harder to maintain and keep write. Thus it is still the wrong thing to do. The justification in the linked document is based on trying to optimize the code. This is premature optimization, trying to save a few cycles at the cost of making the code brittle (as even admitted in the linked document). But anything you save will nearly always be automatically saved by any good optimizing compiler. So there is absolutely **no benefit** in modern compilers and it makes the code brittle.

Comment: Try writing the code both ways and compiling it with full optimizations. You will find there is no extra cost.

Comment: @LokiAstari, for vector - there will be almost no extra cost (or about 50% extra cost, if loop body is light). But for, say, `set`, `end()` is really heavy operation. Also, I don't get why code becomes brittle. Doing this you explicitly say that you won't modify container, it clarifies intentions, and make code robust to occasional changes in algorithm.

Comment: Both those assertions are false: 1) the cost for vector is 0 (try it). The cost for end() is not that heavy. Even if they don't cache end() RVO/NVRO will make the cost very small. If they do cache the value of end() (which they do) the cost is again 0. Its brittle because you have to know that loop needs changing if you modify what the body of the loop does. If you change code in one place and this **requires** a change somewhere else (that is not obvious) it makes the code brittle as it is now a maintenance nightmare. This is just a case of pre-mature optimization with no real gain.

Comment: Please try it. I have. The difference in the generated assemble is so minor as to be insignificant. Thus I will always go with the code that won't break when I modify it.

Comment: Note: set.end() -> rb_tree.end() -> returns head node pointer wrapped in iterator object. The cost of construction of the iterator object which is a one member structure with no virtual methods is thus optimized to zero and is just the cost of copying a pointer out of the method, but since the method is inlined the cost is zero. Inlining and RVO save the world from premature optimizations again.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I tried. `set::end()` is heavy because there is some branches and loop, because `set` is a rb-tree.

Comment: @Abyz: I have already shown that statement to be false. set:end() -> rb_tree:end() -> Iterator(head). There are **no branches** and **no looping**.

Comment: @LokiAstari, maybe, on your compiler. I used MSVC2010.

Comment: The standard guarantees that end() has a complexity of O(1). That means they **can not** use a loop (not one that is dependent on the size of the set). http://stackoverflow.com/q/181693/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari, OK, MSVC2010 violates the standard. But the standard don't compile code for me, so I prefer to use practices suitable for real compilers.

Comment: @Abyx MSVC is known to have additional runtime checks on by default, even for release builds. Microsoft has chosen that the default should err on the side of safety. Search MSDN for `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` and `_SECURE_SCL` for more details, including how to disable them. And yes, it makes a measurable difference!

Comment: @Abyx I've looked at the MSVC2010 code. `std::set<T>::begin()` creates an iterator, based on `_Lmost()` and a pointer to the container itself. The latter will repeatedly be forwarded to a base class, till one hits either `_Iterator_base0` or `_Iterator_base12`, depending on the iterator debug level. `_Iterator_base0` does not store the pointer, while `_Iterator_base12` does. The latter also (un)registers itself at the container. The unregistering contains a loop, which might be what you traced. That loop is over the number of iterators to a container, so technically O(1).